# Not able to use Rscript with exec() inside php in lampp

Tags: php, r, lampp

I want to call a R script inside php (which I am running through xampp in Ubuntu) using the exec function as shown in the code below. I am able to run the same R script through commandline. The problem is that the R script is not running when invoked through php as shown in the code below. Would really appreciate any suggestions on how to go about to solve the problem.

```html
<?php
exec("Rscript rscript.R");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a test page</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The R script is

```html
x <- rnorm(5,0,1)
 
png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
hist(x, col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Are you sure that you know where the working directory was when the exec() was called? Perhaps explicitly setting the working directory in your rscript.R? I also worry about naming files with the same name as executables. Even if the system is able to keep track of the differences, human brains may get confused.

Comment: No I am pretty sure everything is in the same place (have check and verified it).

Comment: You have not convinced me that you have "checked and verified it". You are complaining that no file is produced and I am suggesting it may be in a location that you didn't expect. I was suggesting that you use something like `setwd("/Users/your_user_name/")` just before the R plotting functions. I see no evidence that you have attempted that.